# Xcode - String passed to second ViewController through segue returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, segue

I'm trying to pass an NSString from ViewController to secondViewController, but the value returns `null`. I'm using Storyboards and a present modally segue that fires when the `selectDateButton` is pressed.

The user selects a date using a `UIDatePicker`, the value is then formatted to MM/dd and put into an NSString ivar. I'm taking that ivar and setting it to a property in my secondViewController. I'm pretty sure my mistake's probably in the way I've written it in the `prepareForSegue` section.

I've also tried writing it as `svc.theDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", selectedDateString];` to no avail.

I have no idea why this is happening and would appreciate some help.

ViewController.h

```
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

    NSDate *selectedDate;
    NSString *selectedDateString;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)selectDateButton:(id)sender {
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];

    selectedDate = [datePicker date];
    selectedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toSecondViewController"]) {
        secondViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController];
        svc.theDate = selectedDateString;
    }
}
```

secondViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"
    @interface secondViewController : UIViewController {}

    @property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *theDate;
    - (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
@end
```

secondViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Selected Date: %@", _theDate);
}
```

Comment: Is your destination view controller class `secondViewController` or is it `Birthday Screen`?

Comment: Forgot to edit that while changing my code for the post. Problem still persists regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that instance variables in Objective-C by default have the

```
@protected
```

storage qualifier. That means **only the class itself and its subclasses** can access the instance variable. 
However, what you are actually doing in prepareforSegue is this:

```
svc.theDate = selectedDateString;
```

i.e. you are **passing a reference** to the selectedDateString instance variable via a setter method to the BirthDayScreen view controller instance, which **does not have access** to selectedDateString instance variable. Why?  Because it is not related in any way to the ViewController class and the variable itself **is not public.**

Later when you try to possibly show the string in UI, you actually have a reference to the ivar in the ViewController instance but it is not accessible so you get null.

You could explicitly make it public in ViewController

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

    NSDate *selectedDate;
    @public NSString *selectedDateString;
```

}

But actually this is not the right approach.

Instead, try changing the storage qualifier for the theDate property to

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString *theDate;
```

This will create a new instance of NSString that will be a copy of the NSString represented by the selectedDateString variable, but this new copied instance **will belong** to the SecondViewController.

If it is not enough and still not work (it should) , instead of having instance variables in the ViewController header, create a proper public property called selectedDateString.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    NSDate *selectedDate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedDateString;
```

This way you will expose the value of the backing _selectedDateString to the outside world.

Comment: This is it, but for some reason it still wasn't working. I ended up recreating the project and rewrote every bit correctly and it finally works! I think the part that broke it was having the same button set the value of `selectedDateString` and present the new screen modally. I assigned one button just for changing screens and another for setting the value, and it works.

Comment: Update: In order to use one button to do both, instead of linking that button with a segue to another view controller by right clicking in StoryBoards, I ended up setting up a manual view controller and calling it after the button sets the value in its method.

Answer (score -1):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *theDate;





- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 

 {

   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


   NSString *str = [NSString StringWithFormate:@"%@",appDelegate.imageStringName];

  NSLog(@"str : %@",str);

}
```